# Can I HitTest element with lower ZIndex in WPF Canvas?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, hittest

When I am using `System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper.HitTest` on mouse clicking canvas, it always returns me the element on top. I mean if there are two elements overlapping each other, the one I get is the one with higher ZIndex in canvas.

I also tried to do it [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10100994/how-to-get-control-with-lower-zindex-when-mouse-clicked-in-wpf), but even after I made `IsHitTestVisible = False` it still returned this same one to me.

Is there any possibility to get the element "underneath"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the section "Hit Testing and Z-Order" here: [Hit Testing in the Visual Layer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752097%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and a code example here: [VisualTreeHelper.HitTest Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms608753%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

In short, you need to use one of the `HitTest()` methods that take a `HitTestResultCallback`, and then from your callback return `HitTestResultBehavior.Continue` until you reach the element you're looking for:

```
Point pt = ...
VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(myCanvas, null,
                         new HitTestResultCallback(MyHitTestResult),
                         new PointHitTestParameters(pt));
...

private HitTestResultBehavior MyHitTestResult(HitTestResult result)
{
    DoSomethingWith(result.VisualHit);

    //Set the behavior to return visuals at all z-order levels. 
    return HitTestResultBehavior.Continue;
}
```

Comment: Works wonders! It took me time to adjust it but when I did - it just went great!