# Listview overlay and highlighting listview items

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a ListView wrapped in Grid on top of which I have a panel overlay( [How to make overlay control above all other controls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450985/how-to-make-overlay-control-above-all-other-controls)). I would like to highlight a listview item that is under even when the cursor is not directly over it.

[image]

I would like to have a highlight like this when the cursor is over the red rectangle.

[image]

```
<Grid Name="grid">
    <ListView Name="timeSpansListBox" SelectionMode="Extended" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="{Binding ElementName=timePanel, Path=ActualWidth}">
      ...
    </ListView>
    <!-- our overlay -->
    <MyPanel Name="timePanel" Panel.ZIndex="999">
      ... items (rectangles you can see on the image)
    </MyPanel>
</Grid>
```

How could I do this?

Similar issue: [How to get control with lower zindex when mouse clicked in wpf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10100994/how-to-get-control-with-lower-zindex-when-mouse-clicked-in-wpf)

I could set `IsHitTestVisible` to `false` but I need panel items to remain clickable so it's not an option.

If only there is some way to set `IsMouseOver` programmatically...

Answer (score 0):

Set the vertical and horizontal alignment to stretch for the overlay panel

```
<MyPanel Name="timePanel" Panel.ZIndex="999"
         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
         VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    ... items (rectangles you can see on the image)
</MyPanel>
```